# How can we run the native Mongo script with Mongo Client

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have tried the below code, I know there was db.eval(query) to run a native script. which is removed after mongo 4.0. is there a way to just run the mongo query using mongoclient. i tried run command but it needs parameter of type Bson

```
final String mongoUri = buildMongoURI(connectionUri, username, password);
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoUri)) {
            Document doc = Document.parse("{\"by\": \"tutorials point\"}");
            Document executionPlan = mongoClient.getDatabase(findDatabaseNameInMongoURI(mongoUri)).runCommand(doc);
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(findDatabaseNameInMongoURI(mongoUri));
            MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("deploy");
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you can execute a document. You can insert/update/delete a document but you cannot execute it, i.e. `runCommand`

Comment: Option `--eval` is available in the `mongo` (or `mogosh`) shell. No idea whether it exists in Java driver.

Comment: it was existing before mongo driver 4.0. but they have removed it